# Time complexity of remove extra spaces function

Tags: java

I wrote a function that gets rid of consecutive spaces with a single space without the use of replace functions. However, I am confused about the time complexity of the function/if there is a better way to implement it.

```
static String removeSpaces(String s){
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    if (s == null){
        return "";
    }
    if (s.length() == 0){
        return "";
    }
    for (int i=0;i<s.length();i++){
        if (s.charAt(i) == ' '){
            sb.append(" ");
            if (i < s.length() - 1){
                while (s.charAt(i) == ' '){
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }
        sb.append(s.charAt(i));

    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: You should look for correctness first. Your code breaks if there are multiple spaces at the end.

Comment: Your code is O(n), which any conceivable implementation of this function would be, so stop worrying.  That said, use `StringBuilder` instead of `StringBuffer`.

Comment: Your code looks almost correct, but I found the fact that you have two appends a bit confusing. It is easier to reason about if you replace them with a single `sb.append(s.charAt(i))` as the first statement in your loop.

Comment: This belongs on code review

Comment: @Smac89 At least part of it. Asking about the time complexity does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should care for correctness. Your innermost loop, `while (s.charAt(i) == ' '){ i++; }` doesn’t check the boundaries and will break once your code enters it, which will happen if there are multiple spaces at the end of the `String`.

Besides that, the time complexity is `O(n)` and you can’t improve the complexity. This doesn’t mean, that there aren’t things you can’t improve. The complexity only tells you, how a solution *scales* with large numbers, i.e. larger `String`s in this case.

Consider:

```
static String removeSpaces(String s) {
    // check preconditions for fast exit before creating new objects
    if (s == null || s.isEmpty()) {
        return "";
    }
    // use StringBuilder for pure local operations to avoid synchronization costs
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i=0;i<s.length();i++) {
        sb.append(s.charAt(i)); // the code is always the same for all characters
        // now skip runs of spaces
        if(s.charAt(i)==' ') {
            while(i<s.length()-1 && s.charAt(i+1) == ' ') {
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

First of all, this code is *simpler*, which might turn out to be more important than minor improvements in execution speed, however, most environments tend to execute smaller loops faster.

However, the time complexity still is `O(n)`…

---

But note that you can simplify the entire operation to `return s.replaceAll(" +", " ");`…

Comment: "this code is simpler, which might turn out to be more important than minor improvements in execution speed" -- Yes, yes, a thousand times yes.

Comment: Hey I tried running this but it ended up cutting off the first character of each word after the first one: 
running
    removeSpaces("hello          my     name is matthew               e .   ");
gave me
"hello y ame s atthew   "

Comment: @scatta678: I already fixed that. Turned out that one minute was too little for testing. Note that I added an even shorter alternative.

Comment: To remove leading space, `int i = 0; while(i < s.Length && s[i] == '  ') i++;` To remove trailing spaces, `int z = s.Length - 1; while(z>0 & s[z] = ' ') z--;` All done before loop. In for loop, `for(;i<=z;i++)`

Comment: @camrydash this question isn't about removing leading space or trailing space

Answer (score 0):

*Update according to the comment of @Dukeling*

In the worst case you will have about n^2 loops, where n is the length of the string. Therefore the complexity is O(n^2). Of' course this is the worst case and since the inner loop just skips spaces n^2 loops will almost never happen. Therefore maybe you should check the amortized complexity.

Comment: There's also a while loop inside the for loop, so the explanation isn't quite this straight-forward.

Comment: @Dukeling: You are correct, I missed it. I updated my answer.

Comment: The worst-case complexity is O(n) because the inner loop uses the same variable as the outer loop.

Comment: Just because there are two nested loops, it isn’t automatically `O(n²)`. The inner loop advances the outer loop’s index, so characters processed by the inner loop are not processed by the outer loop. So it is effectively only *one* loop which is syntactically separated. The time complexity still is `O(n)`. Dukeling’s first comment only said that your *explanation* is not entirely correct, it was not objecting the conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

The complexity of the program is **O(n)**, as you are iterating every character of the string only once.

You can use the below code removing the consecutive space, keeping one space. It uses `StringBuilder` instead of `StringBuffer`.

1. You don't need extra `if condition` once you encounter the white space.
2. don't increment the `i` in `for loop`, because you are also incrementing in while loop.
3. check the `i < length`, before check white space in while loop.

```
static String removeSpaces(String s){
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  if (s == null){
    return "";
  }
  if (s.length() == 0){
    return "";
  }
  for (int i=0;i<s.length();){
    if (s.charAt(i) == ' '){
      sb.append(" ");
      while (i < s.length() && s.charAt(i) == ' '){
        i++;
      }
    } else {
      sb.append(s.charAt(i));
      i++;
    }
  }
  return sb.toString();
}
```

**Note :** This will not remove the **leading** and **trailing** space completely. Only multiple white spaces are removed and only one is kept.

Comment: @scatta678 what happened?

Comment: @scatta678 did you run into any issues?

Answer (score 0):

There is not much you can do on complexity but you can fix and improve the implementation :

- If you don't require synchronization use a StringBuffer.
- use a variable to store the length of your String instead of calling s.length() every time.